# why does assigning a number to an array make the array object a nan?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
function bytesToMb(arr)
{
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;arr++)
    {
        var mbs= arr[i]/(1000*1000);

        arr[i]=mbs;
    }

    return arr;
}
```

after the line `arr[i]=mbs` executes, the value of `arr` (the array object itself) becomes NAN.
why is that????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are incrementing arr, arr + 1 = NaN because array is NaN; you ought to do i++ in your for loop instead...

Answer (score 1):

You're using `arr++` instead of `i++` as the third clause in your `for` loop.

The type coercion from `Array` to `Number` leads to your `NaN`.

Answer (score 1):

Change `arr++` to `i++`

```
function bytesToMb(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var mbs = arr[i] / (1024 * 1024); // you should use 1024*1024 here to make it more precise if you need to.
        arr[i] = mbs;
    }
    return arr;
}
```